# How to define a foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

my two parents table are **person** and  **artwork**. I created their table as follows:

```
create table person (
     person_id number(20) primary key,
     name varchar2(20),
     address varchar(50),
     contact_number number (10)
     );
```

and other

```
 create table artwork (
    artwork_id number primary key,
    barcode char (20),
    title varchar2(20),
    description varchar2(50));
```

When I try to make the child table **vote** it is giving this error.

```
   create table vote 
    (
        vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
        artwork_id number(20),
        person_id number(20),

        PRIMARY KEY (vote_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY (artwork_id) REFERENCES artwork(artwork_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY ( person_id) REFERENCES Person(person_id)
    );
```

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "FOREIGN KE..." - rest of line ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove that blank line before the definition of your constraints when creating the vote table:

```
create table vote 
(
    vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
    artwork_id number(20),
    person_id number(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (vote_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (artwork_id) REFERENCES artwork(artwork_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY ( person_id) REFERENCES Person(person_id)
);
```

Any blank rows will stop SQL*Plus from accepting input lines.

If you want it to avoid this run:

```
  set sqlblanklines on
```

before any other instruction.

Comment: just want to ask another query with my table artwork I want to add artist_id as a FK.  
     `create table artwork (
    artwork_id number primary key,
    barcode char (20),
    title varchar2(20),
    description varchar2(50),
    artist_id varchar2(10),
 FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist(artist_id)
);`  ** ERROR at line 7:
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type**    SOLVED NOW ,I used diff data type in artis_id in another table.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to mention `constraint` before `foreign key`:

```
create table vote 
(
    vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
    artwork_id number(20),
    person_id number(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (vote_id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_artwork_id FOREIGN KEY (artwork_id) REFERENCES artwork(artwork_id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_person_id FOREIGN KEY ( person_id) REFERENCES Person(person_id)
);
```

**Syntax**

> The syntax for creating a foreign key using a CREATE TABLE statement
>   is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
);
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d141

**Explanation**

By default SQL*Plus doesn't like blank lines. However we can easily configure our SQL*Plus environment to ignore them:

```
SQL>  set sqlblanklines on
```

We can also put the setting in our glogin.sql file (assuming we're allowed to edit it, which isn't always the case).

Comment: SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CONSTRAINT..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: First run `set sqlblanklines on` command and then try @agam2104

Comment: Run the above `create table vote ` query that one is the correct code

Comment: Added explanation @agam2104